# Pandas: Update column based on row values

Tags: python, performance, loops, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 million rows and three columns. I need to update the counter column based on last 3 values of each key. On row iteration, I keep last 3 values of any key in an array item and count how many times all items in the array are greater than 2 (if all items > 2 add counter by 10 for that key)

initially, there are two arrays for ID=1 and ID=2

```
for ID=1, window=[1,1,1]  and for ID=2, window=[1,1,1]

ID value counter
1   3     0
1   2     0
2   1     0     
1   2     0
2   4     0
2   6     0
1   3     0
1   2     0
1   1     0
2   3     0
1   4     0
1   5     0
```

it will be :

```
ID value counter
1   3     0
1   2     0
2   1     0     
1   2     10
2   4     0
2   6     0
1   3     20
1   2     30
1   1     30
2   3     10
1   4     30
1   5     30
```

for ID=1 ==> [1,1,1]  [1,1,3]  [1,3,2]  [3,2,2]  [2,2,3] [2,3,2] [3,2,1] [2,1,4] [1,4,5]

for ID=2 ==> [1,1,1]  [1,1,1]  [1,1,4]  [1,4,6]  [4,6,3]

The problem is it takes too much time to iterate on rows. Any suggestion to improve the performance? Sorry in advance if the question is not really clear.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to iterate over the rows in a DataFrame by rows of three and apply some function to it?

Comment: I iterate rows and check the last 3 values for the row's key. If all three values are greater than 2, then I update the row's counter, otherwise, I go to the next row.

Comment: OK, so you iterate over every row and look at the values of the last three. What exactly do you mean by key? How do you determine the value of the key? Do you mean the "ID" column?

Comment: key is column ID. if the next row's ID is 1, I check last three values for ID=1 and add row's counter by 10 if all three values are greater than 2

Comment: So in the first iteration for key=1 you have the ID values [1, 1, 2], the next ID is 1, all values are greater than or equal to 2 for all three values with ID 1, so the fourth row has counter value set to 1o. On the next iteration you have the ID values [1, 2, 1], with the next ID value being 2, since you don't have three values for ID 1, counter stays the same. And on and on, is this correct?

Comment: No, Initially the window for ID=1 is [1, 1, 1]. The next value is 3 so the window will be [1, 1, 3] . In the second iteration, the value is 2, so the window will be [1, 3, 2]  . The window is a deque

Comment: The window is filled with row's value